# Job status after ssh session stopped on MobaXterm

Tags: mobaxterm, rclone

I am copying some large datasets to google drive using rclone sync in Linux on MobaXterm. I submit the job as below;

```
-cpu:~$ nohup rclone sync /path_to_source/. /path_to_destination &
 [1] 16310
```

and when do 'jobs' to see job status, it is running.

```
-cpu:~$jobs
[1]-  Running       nohup rclone sync /path_to_source `/path_to_destination &`
```

However, maybe a couple of hours later the session stops for some reason;

```
Session stopped
    - Press <return> to exit tab
    - Press R to restart session
    - Press S to save terminal output to file

Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

So I restart the session, login and I do 'jobs' nothing is shown.

```
-`cpu:~$jobs`
-`cpu:~$
```

I know that the job is not completed yet, because I used nohup, also when I run the same sync command line above it is still copying.

After i restart the session and use 'jobs' why i cant see jobs running? Or how can I see it, possibly with job ids, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jobs` command/utility/shell built-in only lists jobs associated with the current session of the shell. The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html) defines this behaviour:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The jobs utility shall display the status of jobs that were started in
>   the current shell environment; see Shell Execution Environment.

When the original session is interrupted and you re-connect to the system, you end up in a different session (or a different 'Shell Execution Environment' to avoid confusion). Inside this new session, the shell will not track jobs that were started from the previous session.

Since you have already used the `nohup` command along with the `&` operator to background the command, you should still see it running on the system. Running `ps -ef | grep rclone` should show you the running process.

Related QA: [Why does the jobs command not work in shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/284129/173368), [command “jobs” cannot see the stopped jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172477/173368).

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful. I  tried  -cpu:~$ ps -ef | grep rclone
  10399     1 13 Mar22 ?        05:33:27 rclone sync ... Is this mean this job with Id 10399 is stopped or running? I have checked the link you added above and tried ps -t pts/42
error: TTY could not be found. thanks

Comment: @kutlus The number '10399' is a process identifier, or PID for short. It's the first column in the output of the `ps` command you've shown here. So yes, the same process is still running.

Comment: @kutlus The second part about the `ps` command's error is a bit different. Each shell session also has an identifier, and the `-t` option allows you to see the processes created from one or more specific sessions. In your case, the original session for the `rclone` command is gone, so you'll see a '?' character instead in the `ps` output (after the 'Mar22' column). The specific identifier 'pts/42' from the QA is just an example, and it's probably not a valid identifier on your system.